# How to translate "chivvying from"

Tags: meaning, verbs

What does "**chivvying from**" mean in this sentence:

> But a nice young man who wanted *a bit of chivvying* from a jolly girl-friend.

Comment: This word appears to be in standard dictionaries see https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chivvy?q=chivvy

Comment: @JamesK - the dictionary entry doesn't explain what "a bit of chivvying" mean?

Comment: I invite Vitaly to [edit] the question to clarify if that is the problem

Comment: Could you tell us the source of the sentence, adding context is often helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It could mean several things depending on the context.

I sometimes read P.G. Wodehouse stories there a 'but a nice young man who wanted a bit of chivvying from a jolly girl-friend' might describe one of Berty Wooosters friends. 
They are often well educated men from the upper classes who are feckless and need the motivation of a woman to make something of themselves rather than spending time in the Drones club drinking and up to othe highjinks.

(To me the phrasing of sentence seems quite like something Wodehouse might have written).

But the general idea, and not necessarily from a Wodehouse story,  would be that other people think that the young man in question would be improved by having a girl-friend that would motivate him by making small jibes and comments that perhaps other people he was not in love with could not make.

Answer (score 0):

Per se, the verb "*to chivy*" (or '*chivvy*') has plenty of meanings:

1. To annoy or bother
2. To tease with persistent petty attacks
3. To obtain by small maneuvers

As for the meaning within this context, it probably means "*playing a game of chase*":

> Probably the young man wanted the girl to chase him, or maybe pester or bother.

- **a bit of chivvying** - means "*some amount of action*" implied by this verb.

Comment: he can't want chasing as it is from his girlfriend